# Understanding XAML syntax

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a Theme attribute that I can load like this:

```
 <xcad:DockingManager>
            <xcad:DockingManager.Theme>
                <xcad:AeroTheme>
                </xcad:AeroTheme>
            </xcad:DockingManager.Theme>
```

AeroTheme is a class. How can I achieve the same result via attributes?

```
 <xcad:DockingManager  Theme="What should I write here?">
```

Comment: Seems pretty straight forward to me, did you run into any problems with the usual combination of `<Resources>`, `x:Key=` and `{StaticResource key}`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an instance of that theme, which you can provide as a static resource. For example if the parent control is a grid:

```
<Grid.Resources>
  <xcad:AeroTheme x:Key="myTheme"/>
</Grid.Resources>

<xcad:DockingManager Theme="{StaticResource myTheme}">
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, it's impossible to set a property of a complex type (a class for example) via attribute in xaml without declaring this object in Xaml explicitelly. When XAML is parsed the actual object tree is being constructed. Xaml give you the possibility to use attributes in much more extended way than common XML. In particular, you can write something like this:

```
<Grid Backgroud="Red"/>
```

In compile time, Red is nothing more than string value. However WPF does the magic behind the scene. The magic is that WPF read the type of property via reflection (in this example Background property type is a `Brush`), it finds `TypeConverterAttribute` on `Brush` class (once again via reflection) and use appropriate classes derieving from `TypeConverter` to make a conversion from string. In this example WPF would use `BrushConverter` class (located in `PresentationCore` assmebly) and call ConvertFrom method to get actual `Brush` object to set the `Background` property.

Of course using this way is not straightforward. In your example, to make it possible you should have the following conditions satisfied:

1. A class `AeroTheme` should be marked with `TypeConverterAttribute`
2. The type specified in the attribute is an instance of `TypeConverter` class.
3. In your `TypeConverter` you have the logic for converting from string to `AeroTheme` object (via implementing method from `TypeConverter`).

Code example:

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(AeroThemeConverter)]
public class AeroTheme
{
    ...
}

public class AeroThemeConverter : TypeConverter
{
    //implementation of convertion here
}
```

In this way if you would have in XAML:

```
 <xcad:DockingManager  Theme="Aero">
```

WPF does the magic and set your Theme property using the conversion written in `AeroThemeConverter`. 
This is of course neighter full nor work example, but it shows the idea. To get more information about this see the MSDN documentation:
 https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typeconverter(v=vs.110).aspx

So the only way to set a property via attribute (without declaring it in XAML) is to make use of the described mechanism.

Another way is to declare an object and use a `MarkupExtension` (`StaticResource`, `DynamicResource`, various types of `Binding` etc) as shown above.